# Transferring Int Array Values to Unsigned Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, int, unsigned

I have some data that comes in as a 32 bit word which represents 32 channels either firing or not firing. I then want to get this data and individually add the channels up as an int so I can find out out many times that channel has fired.

e.g for 4 channels:

001001
001000

Would become:

002001

So far I keep getting this type of error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*(((std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >*)(((long unsigned int)i) * 24ul)) + dat) = data2[i]’
```

Any ideas on how to help me? Thanks =)

```
void binary(int convert,vector <unsigned>* dat) {
    bitset<32> bits(convert);
    //cout << bits.to_string() << endl;
    //cout << bits.to_ulong() << endl;
    char data[32];
    int data2[32];

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
      data[i] = bits[i];
      data2[i] = data[i];
      dat[i] = data2[i]; ///ERROR WAS HERE
    }

    for(unsigned i = 32; i; --i) {
      int j;
      cout << (data2[i-1]);
      }
    cout << endl;
  }


  void SerDi() {
    vector <unsigned> dat(32);

    cout << "    Reading data from memory..." << endl;
    ValVector< uint32_t> data=hw.getNode("SerDi.RAM").readBlock(8);

    hw.dispatch();
    cout << data[0]<<endl;
    cout << data[1]<<endl;
    for (unsigned i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
      binary(data[i], &dat);
    }
    //graph(dat);
  }
```

Comment: And on which line is the error? And can you please edit your question to contain the *complete* error log?

Comment: You guessed correctly =) I'll include the information you asked next time I asked a question =)

Comment: For future reference, you might also want to read [the stackoverflow checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *guessing* this is the line that contains the problem:

```
dat[i] = data2[i];
```

It's because `dat` *is a pointer*, so `dat[i]` is indexing `dat` as a normal array and not a vector object. To solve it, don't pass it as a pointer, pass it by reference instead:

```
void binary(int convert,vector <unsigned>& dat) { ... }
```

and call it without the address-of operator:

```
binary(data[i], dat);
```

---

Or keep the code as it is now, but change the line in question to dereference the pointer instead:

```
(*dat)[i] = data2[i];
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Excuse my very poor knowledge on this as pointers and references confuse me greatly. Do both methods change the value of the vector permanently?

Comment: @fiz The compiler handles references as pointers behind the scenes, and both can be used to modify arguments. However, the syntax between the two is radically different, as you now know.